# Light-driven Carnot engine

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, solar-cells, carnot-cycle

Based on the definition of the Carnot engine, it is reversible, runs in a cycle, and is frictionless, which would result in the conclusion that the Carnot engine is the most efficient engine. The original design of the Carnot engine is working at two different heat sources with fixed temperatures, so the Carnot engine is driven by heat energy. 
My question is:
Is there any type of reversible and frictionless engine that is driven by light radiation energy? Take the solar cell as an example, the photons are absorbed by the solar panels and turned into electrical energy, but how could make this process be reversible and frictionless?